# C# Derivied class doesn't pass values?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have issue (I think) with derived class. When I add some points to my list in `Form 1`, I can see count and iterate through listA, and it seems its okay. I have below code:

```
/* Add points to lists */
class A {
    private Point _singlePoint;
    protected List<Point> _listA = new List<Point>();
    protected List<Point> _listB = new List<Point>();

    //properties
    public List<Point> listA {
        get { return _listA; }
        set { _listA = value; }
    }

    public Point singlePoint {
        get { return _singlePoint; }
        set { _singlePoint = value; }
    }

    public virtual void addToListA(Point a) { }
}

class B : A {
    public override void addToListA(Point a) {
        _listA.Add(a);
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form {

    A _myPoints = new B();
    private void drawPoint()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(txtBoxPointsCount.Text); i++)
        {
            _myPoints.singlePoint = new Point(rnd.Next(100, 300), rnd.Next(100, 300));
            _myPoints.addToListA(_myPoints.singlePoint);
        }

        foreach(Point p in _myPoints.listA)
        {
            graph.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(cPoint), p.X, p.Y, 6, 6);
        }
    }
}
```

In other class I want to do some math on points, but I got `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

```
class D {
    A _myPoints = new B();
    public void calulations(int iterations) {
        randomPoint = rnd.Next(0, _myPoints.listA.Count);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(_myPoints.listA.Count.ToString());

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < _iterations; i++) {
                //here some math
            }
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException e) {
            // here I got errors about no items in my list
        }
    } }
```

In class D, in MsgBox I got count = 0. Maybe I wrote classes in wrong way? Method `drawPoint()` is called before `calculations()`.

Could you help? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think there's some basic confusion here over [instance members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are operating two completely different objects,

You have created an object here

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    A _myPoints = new B();
```

and then in class D created another

```
class D 
{
    A _myPoints = new B();
```

So you are adding point to your first object and trying to access in other object.